# Scale reputation for suggested edits based on the size of the edit

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits

I think you should get different amount of reputation depending on how much of a post you edit. You get `+2` reputation every time you edit. Some of the edits I have done have just been a couple typos while others I basically rewrote the entire post because the guy had horrible grammar. What are your opinions on this?

Comment: How would the system decide that? And what about the possibility that'd encourage people to look to make larger edits than necessary just to try and bump the edit over some threshold that gains extra rep?

Comment: When you do a nice edit, it should be only because you wanna help. There should never be any gamification aspects involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be really hard to implement, and would probably still end up "unfair", so imo it's best to leave it simple.

I have edited questions where the sentences were just all in the wrong order, and I had to move sentence 8 up to after sentence 1, then sentence 11 after (now) sentence 4, glue together short sentences, split up long ones, fix spelling mistakes and punctuation mistakes one character at a time throughout the post, and so on. Other times I just delete two paragraphs at the beginning and one at the end, and insert an image that the OP mentioned in a comment. Way less work, but an automated system might conclude I "changed more."

Then there's the granularity. If you don't raise the amount of rep an edit can earn, you really only have the option of two kinds of edits: 1-rep edits and 2-rep edits. What's the point? And many people would object to the exist of 3-, 4-, or 5-rep edits. Plus, the moment you try to be "fair" you invite people to complain that the automated system didn't correctly award them enough "effort" for their difficult edit, or that someone else got too much.

In the end it comes down to this: if something is a horrible mess, I hope you want to fix it just to make the site better. If not, would 2 rep sweeten the deal for you? Great, edit it. No? Leave it, and hope somebody else edits it. Just as some questions and answers take very little effort and reap a ton of rep, while others take sweat and blood for no reward, so it can be with edits. The system is simple, we hope it all balances out in the end, and if you think something would be more trouble than it's worth, just don't do it. Chances are, someone else will, eventually.